# How to write raw data to usb connected device using .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, cross-platform, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

I would like to write an application that will send raw data to a device that is connected to my mobile phone with Android OS through USB cable. For this purpose, I would like to use .NET MAUI. I know that this is a quite new framework, yet I would like to give it a shot. I'm wondering if there is a way that I can use SerialPort from System.IO namespace or some other library that will allow me to accomplish this task. So far I have found a library [Device.Net](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net) but it didn't support .NET MAUI. I would be very grateful for any hint if/how this is possible.

Comment: USB serial port is available on Maui with : using Android.Hardware.Usb;

Comment: Thanks, @jdweng I didn't know that. Do you know where I can find some examples for .NET MAUI. There are some examples for Xamarin, but I couldn't find any for this new framework. Or, is it somehow transferable for Xamarin to MAUI?

Comment: Serial port code usually transfer easily.  You should be able to use any c# serial port example. Just set Baud Rate correctly to USB speed.  Usually 56K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Activity act = Platform.CurrentActivity;

UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)act.GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);

IDictionary<string, UsbDevice> devicesDictionary = manager.DeviceList;

UsbDevice dvc = devicesDictionary.ElementAt(0).Value;

string ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "rzepak";

var interf = dvc.GetInterface(1);

outEndpoint = interf.GetEndpoint(1);

PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(act, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);

if (manager.HasPermission(dvc) == false)
   manager.RequestPermission(dvc, mPermissionIntent);

deviceConnection = manager.OpenDevice(dvc);

if (deviceConnection != null)
    deviceConnection.ClaimInterface(interf, true).ToString();
    else return false;
```

`deviceConnection` is an `Android.Hardware.Usb.UsbDeviceConnection` type, opened in connect method:

```
byte[] test = new byte[] { input };

if (deviceConnection.BulkTransfer(outEndpoint, test, test.Length, 500) < 0)
    Connected = false;
```

Comment: Where would this code go in the MAUI app? Would it be in the `Platforms  -> Android -> MainAcvtivity.cs` file?