# How to setup back and forth communication between Android and USB connected device (in .NET MAUI)?

Tags: android, maui

I'm developing an app in .NET MAUI, basically only deployed to Android devices. Right now we are implementing a new feature, reading RFID tags with an RFID reader connected over USB. Specifically it is ELTE GPS reader manufacturer.

According to manufacturer, I need to send a specific 36 byte command message to reader and receive a response of same size containing the read tag. I need to setup the connection so I can send this command.

Another issue is how do I listen to the response. I thought of simply waiting a little after sending command and then reading the response from the same deviceConnection object, only using different endpoint, but I don't know which to use. Or should I rather register to some BroadcastReceiver or something?

I tried implementing USB connection described in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73534644/how-to-write-raw-data-to-usb-connected-device-using-net-maui](this question). USB permission works fine and retrieving the USB device and establishing connection too.

However message send always fails on the "deviceConnection.BulkTransfer", and I don't know how to debug this issue, since there is no exception thrown and not much documentation or other info to go on.

Comment: You want to tell me, that the manufacturer of this device, has no demo code whatsoever?

Comment: Not that I know of, unfortunately. I suspect they would prefer you to buy their whole solution including software. But if anyone knows of anything, I would love to see that