# How to open and read from usb serial port in .NET Maui on Android platform?

Tags: android, permissions, serial-port, maui, usbserial

I'm trying to create a .NET Maui application that reads from a device (barcode scanner) connected via usb (rs-232 emulation), but I still can't get the rights to open and the port open. Of course, I am also interested in reading from the port. Please do not have your successful solution available? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in the .NET Maui documentation.

This is my code based on the example from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73534644/how-to-write-raw-data-to-usb-connected-device-using-net-maui]:

```
Activity act = Platform.CurrentActivity;
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)act.GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);
IDictionary<string, UsbDevice> devicesDictionary = manager.DeviceList;
UsbDevice dvc = _usbDevice; // I find _usbDevice successfully

string ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.MauiAndroidSerialPort.USB_PERMISSION";
var interf = dvc.GetInterface(1);
var outEndpoint = interf.GetEndpoint(1);
PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(act, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
if (manager.HasPermission(dvc) == false)
    manager.RequestPermission(dvc, mPermissionIntent);

var deviceConnection = manager.OpenDevice(dvc);

if (deviceConnection != null)
    deviceConnection.ClaimInterface(interf, true).ToString();
```

I get the device but the app crashes on the line
"PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(act, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);"

Answer (score 0):

External barcode scanner acts like an external keyboard and `types` recognized barcode text to the active control.

Have an active text entry control and make sure that it does not lose focus upon scanning with external barcode-reader. And when barcode is read, its value will appear in that control.