# How to get result of granting permission to open and read from usb serial port in .NET Maui on Android platform?

Tags: android, .net, permissions, serial-port, maui

I am trying to create a .NET Maui application that reads from a device (barcode reader) connected via usb (rs-232 emulation). I get the device, force the permission request, but the app continues without waiting for the result of the permission being granted.
Please do not have your successful solution available? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in the .NET Maui documentation.

This is my code based on the example from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73534644/how-to-write-raw-data-to-usb-connected-device-using-net-maui]:

```
Activity act = Platform.CurrentActivity;
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)act.GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);
IDictionary<string, UsbDevice> devicesDictionary = manager.DeviceList;
UsbDevice dvc = _usbDevice; // I find _usbDevice successfully

string ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.MauiAndroidSerialPort.USB_PERMISSION";
var interf = dvc.GetInterface(1);
var outEndpoint = interf.GetEndpoint(1);
PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(act, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
if (manager.HasPermission(dvc) == false)
    manager.RequestPermission(dvc, mPermissionIntent);
//Here I would need the result of enabling permissions

var deviceConnection = manager.OpenDevice(dvc);

if (deviceConnection != null)
    deviceConnection.ClaimInterface(interf, true).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no a such api can get the result of the granting permission when the permision dialog appear. But you can create a new thread to check the permisssion state(`manager.HasPermission(dvc)`) in the loop. Such as this similar thread about [How to handle the Usb Permission Dialog Event on android when using the "device filter" solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73544940/how-to-handle-the-usb-permission-dialog-event-on-android-when-using-the-device).

Or you can try to add a judgement for the following code. Such as:

```
if(manager.HasPermission(dvc))
{
   // do something
}else{
   // do something
}
```